# Understanding Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I am new to using Maven to build projects. I understand that you declare dependencies inside the POM file that outline the jars that are needed for the project so that they get added to the build at compile time.

My question is, how does that work during development, when I need the jar file in order to develop the application? I thought that the point of Maven was that you don't have to actually have the jar file, it gets acquired and put into the war at build time. But if I'm developing and I need a jar file (say Jersey for example), I would still need to go out and grab the jar myself and put it in the lib directory in order to do the development work, right, so that I know what classes/methods are available to me in that .jar? Can someone explain to me what I am missing?

Will my import statements that reference the jersey classes will be resolved at compile time, since right now they are underlined in red since the jar is not currently present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have specified a dependency in Maven pom, then its maven's responsibility to download it. Remember Maven is not bothered whether you code has a dependency on that jar.
So in your ide create Maven project [not simple java project], add all your dependencies in your pom, when you save the pom, all dependencies will be downloaded.
If dependencies are not getting downloaded then you need to check you maven settings.xml file where repository url or credentials might not be correct.

Also want to ad build part details. Maven has lots of plugin available which can help you to package all your dependencies in war file[assembly plugin] or rpm [maven rpm plugin]. These plugins will wrap all your dependencies along with main jar to a single deployable file.

Comment: I think that is the key that I was missing, is that when you save the pom file, the jars are downloaded. Thanks!

Comment: My other question, which is more related to maven, if I am developing on a machine that does not have access to the internet, is there a way that I can have NetBeans point to my local maven repository? Right now, when I try to create a Java Maven Project with netbeans, the creation of the project fails, saying 'no plugin found for the prefix 'archetype'.....

Comment: Projects in all ide's always point to local repository but you will need net access to download dependencies to local respository. In case of internet not working you can also place jars manually in local repository. Maven will download a jar only if that jar version is absent in local repository.

Comment: But as you are new to Maven, i would suggest start with something very simple to grab basic maven stuff and then build a full fledged project. Fixing maven can be very painful job :( ... telling by experience.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption or presumption or conception is wrong.

Let us take an example. You are creating a new web application project

1. Create the project using maven:archetype
2. Convert the project to eclipse compliant (any IDE compliant). This is done by executing one command and this adds the required jars into the class path file and you can develop your application as you normally do.
3. Build and deploy

Comment: 2) is not necessary if the IDE supports Maven directly (e.g. NetBeans)

Comment: Agreed. It is not necessary but more or less needed to do as nobody would like to develop the code in notepad or any other normal editor.

Comment: It just seems strange to me. I understand that at build/compile time, the references to the classes in the jar will be resolved, but if I create a class, import the jersey classes, and start using the classes, how can the compiler know about those classes, since nothing has been downloaded yet.

Comment: What I mean is, that in NetBenas I simply "open" the pom.xml. There is nothing to "convert" because the POM *is* a project definition for NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, with any Java Maven project, you will have to choose the option 'Build With Dependencies', especially if you are using NetBeans. With Eclipse, you can choose, 'Download Sources'. When that is done, the Maven dependencies (the JAR files) with then be downloaded.

In addition, you said that your import statements will be resolved at compile time. This is done when you click the 'Build With Dependencies' option (right-click the Java Project in NetBeans) as this will then download all the dependencies and build the application and resolve any imports that use the JAR libraries found in the pom.xml.

Comment: I see. I guess my misunderstanding is prior to doing a build, when I reference a class in the Jersey jar file, will Eclipse know what I am referring to?

Comment: It should do. I would also make sure that the correct Eclipse Maven plugin is installed as well. (It can be easily forgotten!)